# Unexpected token node express issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mern

When i try calling the endpoint below, i get the error below from postman.

```
{
"success": false,
"error": "Unexpected token / in JSON at position 7"
}
```

- In the `addFollowing` function you can see i've tried log the `userId` and `followingId` but i don't receive any logs from my terminal
- Next i"ve tried using a package this package `npm i json-sanitizer` to sanitize the `req.body` all to no avail

```js
const addFollowing = async (req, res, next) => {
  const userId = req.body.userId;
  const followId = req.body.followId;
  console.log(userId, followId);
  try {
  // Update the user's following list
  const updatedUser = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(
    userId,
    { $addToSet: { following: followId } },
    { new: true }
  ).select("username email following followers");

  if (!updatedUser) {
    return next(new ErrorResponse(404, "User not found"));
  }

  // Update the follower's followers list
  const updatedFollower = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(
    followId,
    { $addToSet: { followers: userId } },
    { new: true }
  ).select("username email following followers");

  if (!updatedFollower) {
    // Roll back the previous update to the user's following list
    await User.findByIdAndUpdate(userId, { $pull: { following: followId } });
    return next(new ErrorResponse(404, "User not found"));
  }

  // Return the updated user and follower objects
  res.json({
    user: updatedUser,
    follower: updatedFollower,
  });
  } catch (err) {
  next(err);
  }
};
```

The very first time i did call this endpoint after writing it, it was successful but subsequent attempts resulted in the above error which i been trying to wrap my head around . Assuch would really appreciate the help. Thanks

Also here's my route

```
router.post("/add-following",protect, addFollowing);
```

Comment: so it means the data is not reaching your server right ? did u tried sending http post method using postman raw json  format

Comment: @NaveenRavi after struggle with this for a few hours, i decided to use the chrome extension thunderClient instead of postman.. and it works . still trying to figure what's the  issue with my postman exactly

Answer (score 0):

it works perfectly fine on thunderclient but doesn't on postman. still can't understand why but trying to . but if anyone faces such an issue in the future just try the vscode extension thunderclient